# Javascript: sequential, not parallel

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I'm working on a project and have trouble to make my javascript work in a sequential way. I know that javascript can execute tasks in parallel so it won't get stuck when you do a request to a server that doesn't respond. This has It's advantages and disadvantages. In my case, It's a pain in the bum.

The scenario is the following, I'm using Firebase to store how many people agree with an opinion. This looks as follows:

I like javascript
- I like it a lot
- I like it
- like nor dislike it
- don't like it
- I basically hate it

People can now select 1 of the options. A record of their selection is then placed under the option. The structure:

```
-dfd21DeH67 : {
    Title : "I like javascript"
    options : {
        0 : {
            option : "I like it a lot"
            agrees : {
                -dfd21DQH6sq7 : "Jhon"
                -dfd21DQH6sq8 : "Luke"
                -dfd21DQH6sq9 : "Bruce"
            }
        }
        1 : {
            option : "I like it"
            agrees : {
                -dfd21DQH6sqA : "Harry"
                -dfd21DQH6sqB : "Jimmy"
            }
        }
        2 : {
            option : "like nor dislike it"
            agrees : {
                -dfd21DQH6sqC : "Timmy"
                -dfd21DQH6sqD : "Paul"
                -dfd21DQH6sqE : "Danny"
                -dfd21DQH6sqF : "Robin"
                -dfd21DQH6sqG : "Dan"
            }
        }
        3 : {
            option : "don't like it"
            agrees : {
                -dfd21DQH6sqH : "Nathan"
                -dfd21DQH6sqI : "Jerry"
            }
        }
        4 : {
            option : "I basically hate it"
            agrees : {
                -dfd21DQH6sqJ : "Tony"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to query it. The results I need for each option are:
- Option (ex. "I like it a lot")
- agree count (ex. n people agreed on this one)
- Percentage (ex. 3 out of 13 said: "I like javascript". this would be ~23%)

Now, getting the "option" and showing this in the browser: success
getting the "agree count": success thanks to `numChildren()`
getting the "percentage": challenge because I need the sum of them all to calculate this.

Any ideas on how to pull this off? Tried pulling off some callback tricks. Unfortunatly to no avail. Below is my vision:

```
//javascript
var hash = "-dfd21DeH67";
var fbDB = new Firebase("https://<MyDB>.firebaseio.com/");
var buffer = [];
var sum;

fbDB.child(hash).once("value", function(opinion) {
    var thisOpinion = opinion.val();

    // First section
    $.each(thisOpinion.options, function(i) {
        fbPoll.child(hash + "/options/" + i + "/agrees").once("value", function(agrees) {
            votes.push(agrees.numChildren());
            sum += agrees.numChildren();
        });
    });

    // execute only if the First section is done
    // this is currently not the case, this gets executed before
    // the first one finishes => result: #ResultsPanel stays empty
    $.each(buffer, function(i) {
        $("#ResultsPanel").append(
            "<div class=\"OptionStatsBlock\">" +
            "Option: " + thisOpinion.options[i].option + "<br>" +
            "Total: " + buffer[i] + "<br>" +
            "Percentage: " + ((buffer[i] / sum) * 100) +
            "</div>"
        );
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I would suggest looking into lodash which can help you when dealing with collections, arrays, and objects.

Comment: Where you're saying "sequential" and "parallel", you seem to refer to things called "synchronous" and "asynchronous". While these concepts may be a big hurdle initially, they are an inherent part of modern web programming.

Comment: @Nijikokun: lodash is a wonderful library. But it doesn't contain anything to make asynchronous calls synchronous, which seems to be what OP struggles with.

Comment: That's true, that's just a matter of learning proper practices there, which isn't too hard.

http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/

The second order of business would be to use promises / some async library to mitigate callback hell.

Then use FP (functional programming) practices to map and reduce for the percentages / totals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As covered in the comments already: you seem to struggle with the asynchronous nature of Firebase (and most of the modern web). I would encourage you to spend as much time on understanding asynchronous programming as it takes to get rid of the pain it currently causes. It will prevent you far more pain down the line.*

### One possible solution

Firebase DataSnapshots always contain all data from under the node that you are requesting. So instead of doing a `once` in a loop (which is almost always a bad idea), you can just request the data one level higher and then loop and use `child`:

```
// First section
$.each(thisOpinion.options, function(i) {
    var agrees = opinion.child("/options/" + i + "/agrees");
    votes.push(agrees.numChildren());
    sum += agrees.numChildren();
});
```

This code executes synchronously.

Note that I didn't test this, so there may be typos. It's basically just a slight modification of your code, that uses `DataSnapshot.child`: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/child.html

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. I guess my thing didn't work because I, and please correct my if I'm wrong, created another asynchronous call within my loop. This caused it to "work in the background" while the rest of the code continues. By using the value of `opinion`, I use data I already know and no extra asynchronous call has to be made, thus resulting in the code being executed as written.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Promise to handle this async nature of calls.
http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Even this post might help you out -
http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/

Answer (score 0):

For one the second $.each is running on an empty buffer array. So it should never even run.

A better approach may be adding an event listener to the "child_added" event similar to below: Referenced from here https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-event-types

```
    var ref = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/fireblog/posts");
    // Retrieve new posts as they are added to Firebase
    ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
      var newPost = snapshot.val();
      console.log("Author: " + newPost.author);
      console.log("Title: " + newPost.title);
    });
```